# MongoDB iteration and update performance issue

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Using pymongo I am iterating over a MongoDB collection of 21.8 million documents  (total size 9.6gb, average size 472b) stored in a single-disk local environment.
I need to update each document in the collection.
I am using skip and limit to obtain results in chunks, and after processing each document, I am passing a series of UpdateOne() methods as part of a bulkWrite process.
The first chunks of the procedure completed very fast, but progressively slowed down. In the middle of the collection (aprox. after 10 million) the process for each chunk is just  taking too long. Is this performance issue normal?
My code is:

```
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
import time

chunksize=1000
collectionsize=db.tweets.count()

starttime=time.time()
for i in range(0,collectionsize,chunksize):
    print('skip',i,'limit',chunksize)
    cursor=db.tweets.find().skip(i).limit(chunksize)
    df=pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

    requests=prepare_bulk_request(df)

    try:
        db.tweets.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
    except BulkWriteError as bwe:
        pprint(bwe.details)


endtime = time.time()
print('total elapsed time ',endtime-starttime)
```

```
#for completeness I am also copying the function definition
def prepare_bulk_request(df):
    """
    :param df: dataframe  (a chunk of the documents collection)
    :return: request job for bulk insert

    """
    # apply geo_to_h3
    resolution=9
    df2=df['location'].apply(lambda row: h3.geo_to_h3(row["coordinates"][0],row["coordinates"][1],resolution))
    df2.name='9'

    resolution=10
    df3=df['location'].apply(lambda row: h3.geo_to_h3(row["coordinates"][0],row["coordinates"][1],resolution))
    df3.name='10'
    df4=pd.concat([df,df2,df3], axis=1)

    def f(x):

        return UpdateOne({'_id': ObjectId(x['_id'])}, {'$set': {'hex':{'9':x['9'],'10':x['10']}}})


    # return list of requests  
    return list(df4.apply(f, axis=1))
```

It seems that I am running out of memory somehow in the process but I don't know why. 
My mongodb version is  3.6.2.

[image: Taskmanager view]

Comment: Using `skip` on a big collection gets slower and slower the further into the collection you go. It would be better to simply iterate over the whole collection cursor and build up bulk-write batches that you execute as you go.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK. I can see now that there is a warning about this in the  [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and a proposed solution based on querying with indexes.